How to execute a coroutine when user clicks on a gameobject?
I am trying to delay the spawning of my prefab, and I tried to do this with coroutines. In play mode, the spawning occurred first, before the Debug message was displayed to show that 2 seconds had elapsed. So I concluded that my Spawn() function is working and my coroutine was executed, just in the wrong order. Below is the code, attached to a game object which will spawn my prefab in its place on click.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EmptyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int id;
    public GameObject camera;
    Coroutine coroutine;

    public IEnumerator DelaySpawn()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        Debug.Log("2 seconds");

    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        coroutine = StartCoroutine(DelaySpawn());
        camera.GetComponent<GameScript>().Spawn(this.gameObject, id);
    }
}


I expected the spawn to be delayed, but it was not. Thank you for helping me out.

Does this answer your question? Coroutine stops working

Yes, thank you, i managed to get a debug message once i removed the code to destroy the object I attached the script to. Im still trying to figure out how to delay spawning though, because currently i get a debug message but its still spawning before the debug...

@SophieLee then I think you should edit/update the question saying the problem is the execution order/delay rather than the debug is not executed at all

ok, the question has been edited! thanks for the help

You should move the spawn code after the yield retrun like the debug you've set up, then the log should be executed at the same time:
public IEnumerator DelaySpawn()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    Debug.Log("2 seconds");
    camera.GetComponent<GameScript>().Spawn(this.gameObject, id);
}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    coroutine = StartCoroutine(DelaySpawn());
}

